# Translating query with GROUP BY and COUNT to Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a query to see how many entities Users have inserted (`Version = 1`) and entities they've updated (`Version > 1`). It queries the entire table and groups by the UserName of the record. This is the raw SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    [s.InternalUser].[UserName],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN s.Version = 1 THEN 1 END) AS [InsertCount],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN s.Version > 1 THEN 1 END) AS [UpdateCount]
FROM [Sale] AS [s]
INNER JOIN [InternalUser] AS [s.InternalUser] ON [s].[InternalUserId] = 
    [s.InternalUser].[InternalUserId]
GROUP BY [s.InternalUser].[UserName]
```

This returns what I want it to. I've tried translating this to a Linq query in a project using EF Core 2.2:

```
var countData = await _context.Sale
.GroupBy(s => s.InternalUser.UserName)
.Select(g => new
{
    UserName = g.Key,
    InsertCount = g.Count(s => s.Version == 1),
    UpdateCount = g.Count(s => s.Version > 1)
})
.ToListAsync();
```

However this results the entire table being loaded and the computations being done in memory:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'GroupBy([s.InternalUser].UserName, [s])' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'where ([s].Version == 1)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'Count()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'where ([s].Version == 1)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'Count()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'where ([s].Version > 1)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'Count()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'where ([s].Version > 1)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'Count()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

It's the `Count()` query that causes it, if I remove that the Group By is translated to the query.

Is there a different way of writing this that would translate to something like the SQL Query I posted before?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Avoid predicate version of `Count` and use the equivalent conditional `Sum`.

In EF Core 3.0+ you can directly replace `Count(condition)` with `Sum(condition ? 1 : 0)`, e.g.

```
var countData = await _context.Sale
    .GroupBy(s => s.InternalUser.UserName)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        UserName = g.Key,
        InsertCount = g.Sum(s => s.Version == 1 ? 1 : 0),
        UpdateCount = g.Sum(s => s.Version > 1 ? 1 : 0),
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

EF Core 2.x supports translation only for `GroupBy` aggregates on simple grouping element property accessors, so you need to preselect the required expressions by using the `GroupBy` overload with element selector, e.g.

```
var countData = await _context.Sale
    .GroupBy(s => s.InternalUser.UserName, s => new
    {
        InsertCount = s.Version == 1 ? 1 : 0,
        UpdateCount = s.Version > 1 ? 1 : 0,
    })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        UserName = g.Key,
        InsertCount = g.Sum(s => s.InsertCount),
        UpdateCount = g.Sum(s => s.UpdateCount),
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Why are we avoiding the predicate version of `Count`?

Comment: @JonathanWood Because it has no direct SQL equivalent (and conditional `Sum` does), so it either is not translated (EF Core up to now) or get worse and inefficient translation (EF6).