# Entity Framework Core: Group by using calculated field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to write a query. What I have so far is shown below.

```
var x = from d in DbContext.StorageDetails

        let state = (d.ReleaseDate.HasValue && d.ReleaseDate < date) || (d.TakeOrPayEndDate.HasValue && d.TakeOrPayEndDate < date) ?
                StorageState.Closed :
                (d.RailcarNumber == null || d.RailcarNumber == string.Empty) ?
                    d.TakeOrPayStartDate.HasValue ? StorageState.TakeOrPay : StorageState.Open :
                    (d.ArrivalDate.HasValue && d.ArrivalDate <= date) ? StorageState.Filled : StorageState.EnRoute

        group d by new
        {
            d.CustomerId,
            d.Customer.Name,
            d.LocationId,
            d.Location.City,
            d.Location.State
        } into g

        select new
        {
            // ...
        };
```

The part that's giving me trouble is that I want to include the calculated `state` value with each item. I don't want to group by this value but I want to be able to sum it.

```
// Note: This is after my group statement
select new
{
    // state is a let variable and not part of x!
    TotalOpen = g.Sum(x => x.state == StorageState.Open),
    TotalClosed = g.Sum(x => x.state == StorageState.Closed),
    // Etc.
};
```

Is there a way to do this? I don't seem able to `select` my own set of columns prior to `group by`. How can I insert this calculated field into each item?

*Note: `StorageState` is an enum. I can just as easily cast it to an `int` in all of these expressions. I can figure that part out, but figuring it out is separate from my question here.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219785/discussion-on-question-by-jonathan-wood-entity-framework-core-group-by-using-ca).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you would write this as a query expression, nor if EF can translate that expression to sql. I would do something like the following;

```cs
var query = ....
     // Select all the values you need
     .Select(d => new {
        d.CustomerId,
        d.Customer.Name,
        d.LocationId,
        d.Location.City,
        d.Location.State,
        ....
        state = [insert expression]
     })
     // group by this key
     .GroupBy(d => new {
        d.CustomerId,
        d.Name,
        d.LocationId,
        d.City,
        d.State
     }, 
     // and define the final result set
     (d, g) => new {
        d.CustomerId,
        d.Name,
        d.LocationId,
        d.City,
        d.State,
        TotalOpen = g.Sum(x => x.state == StorageState.Open ? 1 : 0),
        TotalClosed = g.Sum(x => x.state == StorageState.Closed ? 1 : 0)
     });
```

I think the sql EF will generate, will put the first select in the from clause, surrounded by your typical select / group by statement.

Comment: Yes, maybe. My problem using a LINQ expression is that I don't seem to be able to do a select before my group by. Here, that's what you're doing. I'll let you know if I can make it work.

Comment: Yeah, the *projection* ***first*** will blow the *translation* out of the water, you would need to `ToList` after it and materialize it. Ef is a little more strict when it comes to grouping, However if you are only using *aggregates* in a post group *projection* it ***may*** figure it out . The other options is just craft a *raw sql* query, or do this in a *stored procedure* to get it all working on the DB

Comment: If EF can't handle it, you could also write a "custom database function" to insert a `(CASE ... END)` snippet of raw sql.

Comment: Even after simplifying my `state` calculation, it complains about the `g.Count()`s. I wonder if it doesn't like the `Select()` before grouping. I will keep experimenting.

Comment: @JonathanWood the only way to get that to work is to use `ToList` after the select. Try doing the state calc in the `Count`, it will be ugly AF, however it has more of a chance of working. But alas, i doubt it will. i think you might need to look at Raw SQL or SP. Here are some words on the limitations of EFCore and GroupBy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby

Comment: I got this working. One thing that wouldn't work was the `g.Count(predicate)`. However, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58102821/translating-query-with-group-by-and-count-to-linq), which says to use `g.Sum(predicate ? 1 : 0)` instead. And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
TotalOpen = g.Sum(x => (x.ReleaseDate.HasValue && x.ReleaseDate < date) || (x.TakeOrPayEndDate.HasValue && x.TakeOrPayEndDate < date) ?
            StorageState.Closed :
            (x.RailcarNumber == null || x.RailcarNumber == string.Empty) ?
                x.TakeOrPayStartDate.HasValue ? StorageState.TakeOrPay : StorageState.Open :
                (x.ArrivalDate.HasValue && x.ArrivalDate <= date) ? StorageState.Filled : StorageState.EnRoute
 == StorageState.Open? 1 : 0)
```

You would repeat the entire expression four times.

Comment: I explained right in my comments there that `state` is not a member of `x`. You didn't understand the question.

Comment: @JonathanWood Fixed it using ternary operator at the end.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two things happening here:

1. `StorageDetails` is queried from `DbContext` and somehow for every item(`d`) found, there's some execution that is being processed to determine the value of `state`...
2. `state` is determined for each `d` and then all the `d`'s are grouped, and then after only few properties of `d` are selected...

This might be another approach:

```
var x = DbContext.StorageDetails
    .GroupBy(d => new
    {
        d.CustomerId,
        d.Name,
        d.LocationId,
        d.City,
        d.State
    }).Select(d => new
    {
        d.CustomerId,
        d.Name,
        d.LocationId,
        d.City,
        d.State,
        d.state = getState(d)
    }).ToList();

int getState(d) 
{
    return (d.ReleaseDate.HasValue && d.ReleaseDate < date) || (d.TakeOrPayEndDate.HasValue && d.TakeOrPayEndDate < date) ?
                StorageState.Closed :
                (d.RailcarNumber == null || d.RailcarNumber == string.Empty) ?
                    d.TakeOrPayStartDate.HasValue ? StorageState.TakeOrPay : StorageState.Open :
                    (d.ArrivalDate.HasValue && d.ArrivalDate <= date) ? StorageState.Filled : StorageState.EnRoute;
}

var TotalOpen = x.Count(x => x.state == StorageState.Open),
var TotalClosed = x.Count(x => x.state == StorageState.Closed)
```

Basically you first get your data from database group it. After grouping it, you then select specific properties and introduce one property called `state`... But state is calculated, using another function which takes a row from database return a value from `enum StorageState` like you have done on the question. Then return the result as list.

Only after you have your list will it be easier to check which of the rows returned contains an `open` or `closed`...

Now you can do normal looping and loop through your `x` and calculate `TotalClosed` and `TotalClosed`.